# Getting the Enum without having to type its class name?

Tags: c#, enums

I notice that in C#, when I have an Enum, say:

```
class ClassObject {
   public static Enum EventType = {Click, Jump, Etc};
}
```

And when I have to access it, I have to go through it's main class and it is very verbose. For eg:

```
ClassObject.EventType.Click
```

I hope that I could access it in a shorter manner, say:
`EventType.Click`, will allow me get that.

So what I thought I could try to create a separate class and extend it from Enum:

```
class EventType : Enum {
   Click, Jump, Etc;
}
```

However, this I'm getting a syntax error for this.

Actually, creating another separate class just for this purpose is a little troublesome and I don't even know if this is a good practice or not. But ideally, I just wish to shorten the name and probably avoid the need for having to type the class name before accessing the enum. Is this possible?

Comment: How come you are encapsulating the enum in a class? How about just doing it in a namespace?

**Just like hunter answered :)

Comment: To be explicit: you can't inherit a class from Enum

Comment: Aren't Enums types? They aren't defined as static.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put the enum at the same depth of the class, it doesn't have to be a class member

```
namespace Test
{
    public enum EventType
    {
        Click,
        Jump,
        Etc
    };

    class ClassObject { }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe I've ever marked an enum as static before. What exactly does that do, and does it make a difference if the enum is declered inside or outside of a class?

Comment: yeah, I don't know why it was `static`, I just copied/pasted.

Comment: There's no reason to declare an `enum` as static. `enums` are types

Answer (score 4):

You are defining the Enum in class scope. That is why you have to access it through class. Define it outside the class and access from every where you like. `Nested Enum and classes are not directly accessible.`

```
public static Enum EventType = {Click, Jump, Etc};

class ClassObject {

}
```