# Typed enum-like representation of table

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I have an "Aspnet_Role" table with string values like "Admin", "Moderator", etc. I would like to have an enum-like representation of these values (updated by hand), but putting an actual enum like this inside the class:

```
public enum Role
{
    None, Admin, Moderator
}
```

causes an awkward use convention: `Aspnet_Role.Role.Admin`. I'd rather be able to do: `Aspnet_Role.Admin`.

I thought of something like string properties:

```
public static string Admin { get { return "Admin"; } }
```

but then I lose the strong typing advantage of the enum. E.g., with an enum I could create a nice helper method like:

```
public static bool IsUserInRole(Aspnet_Role.Role role){
    return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(role.ToString());
}
```

Is there a way to create a strongly typed (i.e. no strings) enum-like enumeration of the values in my table without the `Aspnet_Role.Role` naming and usage?

It would be greatly preferred if each value would only appear in the code once. With just the enum, that would be the case. Using the string properties, it would be twice per value. Using an enum AND properties, like:

```
public static Role Admin { get { return Role.Admin;
```

it would be three times per value! Not pretty. Oh, and please don't suggest `Reflection`. I know you want to.

Comment: Does the enum have to be declared in the class? Can you declare it directly in the namespace and use it as `Role.Admin` instead of `Aspnet_Role.Role.Admin`? See [Getting the Enum without having to type its class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989636/getting-the-enum-without-having-to-type-its-class-name).

Comment: Yes! That would do nicely! I didn't know that was possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per ConnersFan's comment, you can declare the enum in the same namespace as the `Aspnet_Role` class, and use it as desired:

```
namespace DataLayer
{
    public enum Role
    {
        None,
        Admin,
        Etc
    };

    public partial class Aspnet_Role { }
}
```

It would be nice to have some way to indicate that the enum corresponds to the Aspnet_role class somehow. Perhaps via an Attribute?

```
[Represents(Aspnet_Role)]
public enum Role { … }
```

I don't know. Maybe a comment would be better.

Answer (score 0):

At first - I'd store the role in the database as an `integer`, not the `string`.

But if you insist in the string value, create the property like this:

```
public Role UserRole { get; set; }
```

Than you can load it from database and assign it to the property this way:

```
string role = // load it here from db
this.UserRole = (Role)Enum.Parse(typeof(Role), role);
```

But still store it as `int` is the better option.

**EDIT:**

If you would go with the `int` as I advice you, assigning to the property would be:

```
int role = // load it here from db
this.UserRole = (Role)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Role), role);
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question, the op wants to avoid writing `AspNet_Role.Role...`. Your solution won't fix this.

Comment: What is `Role` and `UserRole` in your code? I only have `Aspnet_Role`. As for the ints, this is a legacy system; I don't want to change too much, just make sure new code is better than that which has come before.

Comment: Ok, if I understant id right, do it this way:

`public static Role Admin { get { return Role.Admin; } }`

But I don't see the point of this..

Comment: Role is your enum: `public enum Role { None, Admin, Moderator }`

Comment: Because `Role` has to be inside a type, no? So it would be `Aspnet_role.Role.Admin`. That's the whole point of the question!

Answer (score 0):

Just an example of a type safe enum:

```
public class Aspnet_Role
{
    public static readonly Aspnet_Role None = new Aspnet_Role(Roles.None, "None");
    public static readonly Aspnet_Role Admin = new Aspnet_Role(Roles.Admin, "Admin");
    public static readonly Aspnet_Role Moderator = new Aspnet_Role(Roles.Moderator, "Moderator");

    private Aspnet_Role(Roles role, string name)
    {
        Role = role;
        Name = name;
    }

    public enum Roles
    {
        None,
        Admin,
        Moderator
    }

    public Roles Role { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Aspnet_Role Parse(Roles role)
    {
        switch(role)
        {
            case Roles.Moderator:
                return Moderator;
            case Roles.Admin:
                return Admin;
            case Roles.None:
            default:
                return None;
        }
    }

    public bool IsUserInRole(Aspnet_Role role)
    {
        return Role == role.Role;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Aspnet_Role)
        {
            return Role == ((Aspnet_Role)obj).Role;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I really don't like how each possible value has to be stated _five_ times in the code. I doubt the prettiness of the usage will weigh up to the ugliness of the boilerplate in code reviews…

Comment: Yes it is overkill. I usually use it as an extension of original enum where you could only use integer as the value.